# Want to Create Dynamic Website Embed Link?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

If user reached to website and Current Top URL is "https://website.com/?code=https://webbbb.com"

So I want to Dynamically Set Iframe url "https://webbbb.com" to Embeded Website Link Automatically.

Because I'm Embedding my other Complete Website on my Primary Website...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var queryString = window.location.search; //saving the get params
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); //Documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
    function getIFrameSite() {
        if(urlParams.has("code")){
            document.getElementById('myIframe').src = urlParams.get("code");;
        }    
    }
    getIFrameSite();
</script>
```

Comment: The function is working, the iframe changes thanks to the get param "code". May I know how did you test the function? copy and paste into a html file, open the file and then try adding at the link ?code=<your-page link> be sure that the website you are trying to embed in the iframe is not set up to decline iframes (if you see an error message it mean that the website is not available for iframes embed, you can check that in the console logs of your browser)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It's working but Not working on Google Sites.